# Add priority to producer-consumer design pattern

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have implemented consumer-producer with concurrentLinkedList in java. I need to add a request to the head of the queue instead od its tail, in order to set priority. any idea ? thanks

Comment: Use a PriorityBlockingQueue?

Comment: Switch to ConcurrentLinkedQueue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html